# Cannot install a pod (fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/')

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git, cocoapods

I'm trying to use the command pod install and always have that :

```
$ pod setup

OR

$ sudo pod setup

Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Pod::Executable clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master

Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Failed connect to     github.com:443; Operation timed out

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:217:in `rescue in run': undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:210:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what this is about. Can someone help me? This is the first time I try to do anything with CocoaPods on OS X Mavericks.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods) if you are new to cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

First please check your network, you can use `curl` or `git clone` to check it directly under  terminal

If you have another problem you can try `gem uninstall claide` and then install it

Or you can try ruby 1.9

cocoapods 0.29 and claide 0.4.0 works fine under my ruby 1.9 env

you can use `rvm` to work with different ruby env

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while using a virtual machine. I started getting the error after switching connection to Bridged. The problem was that the machine had no MAC address generated.

> Solution: Go to **Network Adapter settings ->  Advanced -> press
>   Generate MAC Address**